# Is Livepatch supported in 21.04

Tags: 20.04, 21.04, canonical-livepatch

Is Livepatch supported in 21.04?

I only want to install versions that support livepatch. I currently have 20.04 installed and will update to 21.04 if livepatch is available.

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 is **not** a LTS release, thus it's not available

Comment: Also asked at https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2465199

Answer (score 3):

Livepatch is only supported for LTS releases.  21.04 is NOT an LTS release.

LTS releases are clearly marked as LTS releases on [the Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases).

Answer (score 0):

No. Livepatch is only on long term support.
Install 20.04 for if you really need or want to use Livepatch and it's the current long term support at this time of writing.

Hope this help.
Jonathan Steadman :)